# Dynamic exports in an AMD module

Tags: javascript, requirejs, amd

Does AMD allow you to define a module whose exports are dynamic, depending on other modules?

The problem I have is that `define` immediately returns, even if there are `require` calls in the body. This means that, if the module's definition depends on other modules, any module depending on it cannot be sure the module is fully loaded, even though the dependency is fulfilled.

Some code to explain my problem:

```
// A module that exports one function 'f'. The implementation of this f comes
// from another module, dynamically selected based on a condition.
define("mymodule", function (require, exports) {
  var functionImplModule = someCondition ? "function-impl1" : "function-impl2";
  require([functionImplModule], function (functionImpl) {
    exports.f = functionImpl;
  });
});

// Entry point. I want to use module.f in some code.
require(["mymodule"], function (mymodule) {
  // Can't use mymodule.f here yet, because the require() of 'mymodule' isn't done yet
  console.log(mymodule.f);
});
```

Can this be done in AMD? Or how is code like this better structured?

Comment: If I'm interpreting this correctly, you're using [Simplified CommonJS wrapping sugar](http://requirejs.org/docs/whyamd.html#sugar), which relies on magic that parses your source code, necessarily makes simplistic assumptions, and isn't compatible with dynamic dependencies.  What if you rewrite your define the more straightforward AMD way:   `define([someCondition ? "function-impl1" : "function-impl2"], function(functionImpl) {return {f:functionImpl};})`   This assumes your `someCondition` isn't dependent on mymodule's dependencies; if it is dependent, you could add that as clarification.

Answer (score 0):

I would return a `promise` in your `exports`.

```
define("mymodule", function (require, exports) {
  var deferred = ..., functionImplModule = someCondition ? "function-impl1" : "function-impl2";
  require([functionImplModule], function (functionImpl) {
        deferred.resolve(functionImpl);
      });

  exports.f = deferred.promise;
});

// Entry point. I want to use module.f in some code.
require(["mymodule"], function (mymodule) {
   mymodule.f.then(function(impl) ... );
});
```

**Please note** It also appears that you are lazy configuring your module as well. This isn't good for bundling and minification. Perhaps you could use your config to change the which file is used for `mymodule`.

Comment: Thanks. Callbacks/promises were my backup plan, I guess I was hoping there would be something more elegant built-in, especially since it was built for async loading.